# Check Component Dependency, no obvious error

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, composer, php-7, magento-upgrade

I am creating a test environment for magento, hoping that I can replicate later for some work on it, and have come up an issue on Check Component Dependency. the base config is as followed:

Specs are as followed: 
MAMP PRO 4.4.1
M2.1.9 CE (Clean)
php 7.0.27

I have installed as per MAMP Pro advice on their site (https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/How-Tos/General/SetupComposer/), with downloading to composer via Terminal into the magento directory and run the following commands:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

I have also run this command as well as part of a different sequence.

```
php composer-setup.php --install --no-dev
```

but this doesn't seem to work at all, terminal is saying all is ok (install wise), and the PHP is the correct PHP (check with "which php"), given there is a local machine php and mamp pro php.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the following from composer.json and rerunning the readiness check, thought I might share FGOS incase someone else gets stuck on the install/update procedure.

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
```

I also got suck later on the backup, by only checking media that resolved and allowed me to update. not exactly sure why, but given it is a fresh install it may be that there is another in the database to backup, so magento updater is getting confused. Plan to replicate the instance and then do some digging in the future.

Comment: Not sure why the No-dev command didn't work in terminal either, probably something I need to check out, if anyone has any ideas it would be good to know